# Setting Localized String from Code Behind Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, resources

Is it possible to set localized resources from Code Behind to AppResources.resx File? I tried googling it didn't help much either.  When I try to Access AppResources.(Key), I am getting error since there is no setter for the properties :-(

Comment: AppResources should be a class in AppResources.Designer.cs (when you expand AppResources.resx), there you should see that each string is static - you should be able to access it directly from your Namespace. Have you defined other property AppResources?

Comment: When you create blank app and try to test AppResources."yourResource".It's ok?

Answer (score 0):

A localized string is concidered as a constant and should not be modified after its definition. So instead of trying to set your localized String from codebehind or from `AppResources.Designer.cs`, you might want to add a new one using `AppResources.resx`.